# Trigger to update a quantity after deletion

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger named that will automatically update the product quantity on hand for a product when a corresponding product LINE row is deleted. I had no issues creating triggers that can update the same value after an insertion or an update, but for some reason this is getting me confused.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_DELETE
AFTER DELETE ON LINE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
    UPDATE PRODUCT
    SET P_QOH = P_QOH + 
    (SELECT LINE_UNITS 
    FROM LINE
    WHERE LINE.P_CODE = PRODUCT.P_CODE)
    WHERE PRODUCT.P_CODE = :NEW.P_CODE;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product QOH updated');
END;
/
```

All I am trying to do is pass the value that is currently in LINE_UNITS on the row that is to be deleted, and add it to the P_QOH in the PRODUCT table, so that it reflects the correct QOH after deletion. I have tried a few different ways, but so far, no luck. When I try to delete a row, I get an error that says:

> A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
>              this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
>              in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
>   *Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.

Here is another way I tried to do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_DELETE
AFTER DELETE ON LINE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE PRODUCT
    SET P_QOH = P_QOH + LINE_UNITS
    WHERE PRODUCT.P_CODE = :NEW.P_CODE;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product QOH updated');
END;
/
```

This gives me an error saying that LINE_UNITS is an invalid identifier - which I am assuming is because LINE_UNITS is not a part of the PRODUCT table. I have tried LINE.LINE_UNITS as well, to no avail.

I have also tried declaring a variable, setting the variable to the value of the LINE_UNITS, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that you want

```
UPDATE PRODUCT
   SET P_QOH = P_QOH + :OLD.line_units
 WHERE PRODUCT.P_CODE = :OLD.P_CODE;
```

In a row-level trigger for a delete, the `:old` pseudo-record contains the row's data from before the delete operation.  The `:new` pseudo-record will be full of NULL values (just like the `:old` pseudo-record is full of NULL values in a row-level insert trigger).

Comment: Man!!! I was so close, the :old is what did it. I was trying to use :new in a few places and was just not understanding what was going on. It didn't feel right, but my book isn't really explaining it all that well. Thanks for the help sir.